# customize-face and themes bug: workaround?

Tags: themes, customize

I'm seeing the following issue with emacs 25.

I'm confident there must be a workaround for this because I'm in the process of rewriting my emacs configuration, and my old, ugly configuration with the same version of emacs does not have this problem.  Still, while with some effort I've been able to create a minimal failing case (see below), I've not yet been able to create a minimal working case.

Can anybody guess a workaround?  I suspect the problem is related to the fact that `monokai-theme` configures the `whitespace-space` face with some custom elisp.

(By the way, I'd like to report this as a bug but I'm not sure if it's a `monokai-theme` issue or an emacs issue: any pointers there?)

`customize-face` and `monokai-theme` don't seem to be getting along for me with emacs 25:

- Create `~/.emacs.d/init.el` as quoted below and ensure no `~/.emacs` exists
- Ensure `~/.emacs.d/custom-settings.el` does not exist
- Start emacs (I'm using the daily emacs 25 snapshots from https://launchpad.net/~ubuntu-elisp/+archive/ubuntu/ppa on ubuntu xenial)
- Open `init.el`
- `M-x customize-face <RET> whitespace-space <RET>`
- Edit foreground colour and "Save for future sessions" (I had to edit the colour in `monokai-theme's` lisp code to do this: that lisp code appears in the customize UI)
- All good in `custom-settings.el`: my customization appears there
- Quit emacs
- Start emacs
- No errors in *Messages* (and custom-settings.el is unchanged), but `whitespace-space` text now looks the way it did before I customized it, so...
- `M-x customize-face <RET> whitespace-space <RET>`
- Edit foreground colour and "Save for future sessions" (this time, the foreground colour appears in the UI explicitly and the lisp code is gone)
- This time customize reports state "THEMED"
- `init.el` buffer STILL lacks my customization
- On "Save for future sessions", `custom-settings.el` was reset to an empty state (and no I didn't hand edit it!)

here is the "empty state" `custom-settings.el` I refer to above:

```
(custom-set-variables
 ;; custom-set-variables was added by Custom.
 ;; If you edit it by hand, you could mess it up, so be careful.
 ;; Your init file should contain only one such instance.
 ;; If there is more than one, they won't work right.
 )
(custom-set-faces
 ;; custom-set-faces was added by Custom.
 ;; If you edit it by hand, you could mess it up, so be careful.
 ;; Your init file should contain only one such instance.
 ;; If there is more than one, they won't work right.
 )
```

and here's the `init.el`:

```
(require 'package)
(setq package-enable-at-startup nil)
(setq custom-file (concat user-emacs-directory "custom-settings.el"))
(load custom-file t)
(setq package-archives
      '(("gnu" . "http://elpa.gnu.org/packages/")
        ("melpa" . "http://melpa.org/packages/")))
(package-initialize)

(unless (package-installed-p 'use-package)
  (package-refresh-contents)
  (package-install 'use-package))
(setq use-package-verbose t)
(setq use-package-always-ensure t)
(require 'use-package)

(use-package monokai-theme)

(use-package whitespace
  :init
  (global-whitespace-mode 1))
```

Comment: By the way, I tried manually creating a `custom-settings.el`, but have not been able to work around the problem that way

Comment: I also tried using the option in `customize-face` to wipe out the existing `whitespace-space` customization (and then set the foreground colour again), but I wasn't able to work around it that way either

Answer (score 1):

In the end I worked around this with this code in the `:config` section in the `use-package` declaration for `whitespace`:

```
(set-face-attribute 'whitespace-space nil :foreground "#272822")
```